# I create attributes for customer, how to add storefront properties?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, dropdown-attribute

I created a dropdown customer attributes by default Magento2.

I would like to pull this dropdown box out to the checkout page. When customer at checkout page, they will see that dropdown box above shipping method.
I created a field at sales_order and quote table. It will save the value to order as well.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

I have a XML in place, how can I replace the xml and show the customer attributes that I create? I want to to be database driven instead of XML static options.

Thanks